# MIPS assembly , find the letter in a string

Tags: assembly, mips

I wrote this program to find the letter 'a' , 'e', 'i', 'o' and 'u'. it is right to write beq $a0, 0x61,... to find the letter 'a' or I have to use beq $a0, 'a', ....  ?

Also, how can i find 'à' or 'è' ?

this is my program

```
.text
.globl main
main:
la $a0, richiesta
li $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, STRINGA
li $v0,8
syscall

li $s0,0
#la $t0, STRINGA

li $t1, 0               

loop:   lb $a0, STRINGA($t1)
beqz $a0, fine
jal vocale
add $s0,$s0,$v0

addi $t1,$t1,1
j loop

fine:   la $a0, risultato
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0,1
move $a0,$s0
syscall

la $a0, spazio
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall



vocale: li $v0,0
beq  $a0,0x61,trovata
beq  $a0,'e',trovata
beq  $a0,'i',trovata
beq $a0, 'o',trovata
beq $a0, 'u', trovata
beq  $a0,0xe8,trovata

jr $ra  #return
trovata:li $v0,1
jr $ra  #return



.data
STRINGA:                .space 255
richiesta:              .asciiz "Immetti una stringa: "
spazio:                 .asciiz "\n"
risultato:              .asciiz "\nNumero vocali stringa: "
```

Comment: _"it is right to write beq $a0, 0x61,... to find the letter 'a' or I have to use beq $a0, 'a'"_ Any decent assembler would allow both ways, but the latter is much more readable and less error-prone, and is therefore preferred.

Comment: How can i find 'à'? if I write just beq $a0, 'à' it doesn't work

Comment: à is a unicode char/codepoint beyond 0x7F, which means that it is more than a single character. The specific sequence for this in UTF-8 [in hex] is: C3,A0. So, a simple single byte compare won't work.